# Miscellaneous Warning ECONNRESET while setting up vue app

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

I am trying to set up vue app by vue-cli. Everything went well until I typed

```
npm install
```

to install dependencies. It was an error with https so I changed it to http
but then I get this log:

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNRESET: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/debug failed, reason: socket hang up
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
```

I also used

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

and still had the same issue.

Comment: is your machine behind proxy?

Comment: working from home, using local interent provider how to check it?

Comment: then you don't have any proxy setup. Verify if my answer solves your problem

Comment: you can try this one to check if you are behind proxy http://amibehindaproxy.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually change https to http

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

if you are behind proxy else ignore this

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@10.80.81.180:80
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@10.80.81.180:80
```

Install vue-cli

```
npm install -g vue-cli
```

Setup vuejs project

```
vue-init webpack-simple vueproject
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

Now your vuejs boilerplate project setup is complete

**Update #1**

First clear npm cache and then try the above steps

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Comment: @Damien did you follow all the steps ?

Comment: yes i did and still have same out put in console like above

Comment: $ node -v
v8.9.4
$ npm -v
5.2.0

Comment: @Damien create a new project directory and try these steps

Comment: i did everything as you said still same issue

Comment: npm config get registry - what result do you get from this command?

Comment: http:registry.npmjs.org

Comment: @Damien May be you removed forward slash while commenting here. it must be proper url . http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: why not try setting it back to https and verify? npm config set registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"  and also set ssl as true. i don't understand why this is an issue for you.

Comment: Some how it worked but i took several times.... i think problem was git bash terminal

Comment: use command prompt while working with node. use git bash while working with git